# How do I write to a sharepoint webpart zone using javascript?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

For example if I want to do a --> document.write() and write in a web part zone . 
Which ID do I use?
So for example:

```
<asp: Content ContentPlaceholderID="Main"> 
<div class="inner"> 
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="xxx333"><ZoneTemplate> </ZoneTemplate></WebpartPages:WebPartZone> 
</div>
```

I'm familiar with jQuery so an example of that would also be acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Not completely got your req. something like this ...

```
   $('#xxx333 ZoneTemplate').html("..... content ....");
```